# JQuery autosaving for POST form to JSON field in PHP database

Tags: jquery, json, post, get

I originally saved all of the items on the form in a 'TEXT' field on a table using the following PHP code:

```
$the_field = json_encode($_POST);
```

Now I've got to make it save the POST form automatically (when changes are made).

```
$.post("ajax.php?"+$("#form_id").serialize(),
                          { id: '<?php echo $id;?>' },
                     function(data){});
```

ajax.php includes the following code:

```
$the_field = json_encode($_GET);
```

which gives the same result as using json_encode and $_POST originally.

On my server it seems there is a limit of 100 $_GET items including ones in arrays whether the items are one character long or 50+ characters long.

This limit is there for the original page and also for ajax.php

I was wondering if there is an alternative method which doesn't have such a restrictive limit while involving compact code. It should allow arrays... e.g. name="var['.$x.']['.$y.']"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) forms and encode any object into json with javascript.

Look at [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [parse_str()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Edit on OPs request:

Solution:

```
$.post("ajax.php", { data: $("#the_form").serialize()}
```

and for ajax.php:

```
parse_str($_POST['data'], $data_obj);
```

Comment: I used $("#form_id").serialize() to serialize the form.... is there a way to convert a form to json? e.g. something like JSON.stringify($(#form_id)) ?

Comment: When I tried JSON.stringify($("#the_form").serialize()) in the Google Chrome console I just got ""vars%5B1%5D%5B1%5D=X&vars%5B1%5.....5B10%5D=X&test=X""... it was almost the same as $("#the_form").serialize() except that it has an extra set of double quotes at the start and at the end

Comment: proper json is something like {"x":[1,2,3],"y":[4,5,6],"z":"test"}... not ""x=1&y=2&z=3""

Comment: my question is how to convert a form to json... my original method was json_encode($_POST); but I can only figure out how to do that when the page loads. The second method uses GET and serialize but this seems to have a limit of 100 items. I am wondering if there is a way of doing it dynamically (e.g. ajax) without the 100 item limit.

Comment: Solution: $.post("ajax.php", { data: $("#the_form").serialize()},.... and for ajax.php: parse_str($_POST['data'], $data_obj);... then json_encode can be used. It is pretty CPU intensive but it doesn't have the 100 item limit. Could you post that as an answer so I can tick it?

Answer (score 0):

But you can try with `json`:

```
$.post("ajax.php", { id: '<?php echo $id;?>', data: $("#form_id").serialize()}, function(data){
   console.log(data);
}, "json");
```

Comment: For some reason with ,"json" it doesn't work at all. Without ,"json" it logs to the console. ajax.php contains <?php echo 'data:'.$_POST['data'];